# Person is in a lift and the lift is accelerating downwards

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

[image: Question:]

My interpretation of part (ii) is that as $F=ma$, and the lift is going downwards, therefore the weight of the person would be greater than its reaction force. So $W-R=ma$. And $R=W-ma$.

So the answer I got was $(72)(9.8)-(2.5)(72)=525.6N$. However, the answer in the marking scheme say it's in fact $(72)(9.8)+(2.5)(72)=885.6N$.

Also, thinking about it intuitively, if the lift is accelerating downwards, then you feel a lesser force then if it was at rest/constant velocity. Is my interpretation wrong?

Comment: You are correct. The answer the marking scheme gives is for an acceleration *upwards* so there must be a misprint.

Comment: @JohnRennie:  I think the (ii) question is unclear.  The 2.5 m/s/s acceleration is positive which could be interpreted as an upward acceleration.  In other words, the elevator's downward velocity is decreasing.  This would make 885.6N the correct answer after all.

Comment: @James So the elevator is decelerating? I suppose that would make sense when a lift is travelling to the ground floor.